# UITableView repeats first two values

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two different tables side by side to allow a user to select a month and year combination. Each table is populated with values from two different arrays. monthsArray has values '01' - '12' and yearsArray has values '2014' - '2023'. I have verified that the arrays hold the correct values.

The table view height is only large enough to display a little over one row at a time. As the user slides the table up to reveal subsequent values, the values at array places 0 and 1 repeat in both tables. For example, as the months table is scrolled up, this sequence repeats: 01 02 01 02 01 02... The correct number of total rows (12) are presented, but the values are wrong after the 2nd position. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView.frame.size.width == MONTH_COLUMN_WIDTH) return 12;
    else return [self.yearsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    NSLog(@"indexPath: %@", indexPath);
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:DARK_BLUE_RED_COMPONENT green:DARK_BLUE_GREEN_COMPONENT blue:DARK_BLUE_BLUE_COMPONENT alpha:1.0f];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault;

        // add a label for the segment name
        UILabel *label;

        if (tableView.frame.size.width == MONTH_COLUMN_WIDTH) {
            // this is the table to select the expiration month
            label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,MONTH_COLUMN_WIDTH,EXPIRATION_ROW_HEIGHT)];
            label.text = [self.monthsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        } else {
            // this is the table to select the expiration year
            label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,YEAR_COLUMN_WIDTH,EXPIRATION_ROW_HEIGHT)];
            label.text = [self.yearsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        }

        [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:DEFAULT_FONT size:13.0f]];
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [cell addSubview:label];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Here is the NSLog output as I scroll through the left table:

> indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
>   indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}
>  
>   indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}
>   indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 3} 
>   indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 4} 
>   indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 5} 
>   indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 6}
>   indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 7} 
>   indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 8} 
>   indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 9} 
>   indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 10}
>   indexPath:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 11}

EDIT: The comments below are correct, but only partially solved my issue. Now as I scroll through the table, the text seems to get rendered on top of the previous text. By the time I get to the last cell, it's a jumbled mess:

[image]

Comment: The scope of your if (cell == nil){} block looks wrong, once the table has dequeued reusable cells, I can't see where the label gets updated from the data in the array.

Comment: Thanks. This partially solved my problem. Will you please look at the edit?

Comment: Since the cells are reused, you are adding more and more UILabels as subviews. I would either subclass UITableViewCell to provide accessors to custom UI, or use the textLabel property already available to set the string.

Comment: I wound up subclassing it. The textLabel property didn't give me enough control over the layout of the text. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edit you're code just try.

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


  NSLog(@"indexPath: %@", indexPath);
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault;
    }

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:DARK_BLUE_RED_COMPONENT green:DARK_BLUE_GREEN_COMPONENT blue:DARK_BLUE_BLUE_COMPONENT alpha:1.0f];


        // add a label for the segment name
        UILabel *label;

        if (tableView.frame.size.width == MONTH_COLUMN_WIDTH) {
            // this is the table to select the expiration month
            label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,MONTH_COLUMN_WIDTH,EXPIRATION_ROW_HEIGHT)];
            label.text = [self.monthsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        } else {
            // this is the table to select the expiration year
            label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,YEAR_COLUMN_WIDTH,EXPIRATION_ROW_HEIGHT)];
            label.text = [self.yearsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        }

        [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:DEFAULT_FONT size:13.0f]];
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [cell addSubview:label];

    return cell;
}
```